# Displaying product categories

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, categories

I'm creating a simple website for a business to display their products. On the index page I display the 3 newest products. What I need to do now is have a category page people can go to to view products in a certain category. I tried adapting the code from my index page but the products aren't showing up on my category.php.

I have a product_list.php with the different categories, when one is selected I'm trying to load category.php with the products from the category that was selected.

What I have:

### product_list.php

```
<?php
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<meta name="Description" content="Lightweight aluminum boat docks, lifts, and accessories" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Aluminum boat dock ladder lift water wheels" />
<script src="scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<title><?php echo $product_name; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</style>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
<?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" align="center"><table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><p>Aluminum Docks</p>
        <p><a href="category.php?category=docks"><img src="inventory_images/aluminum docks/PN99002-6_24x4_PKG_LG.jpg" width="100" height="64" alt="24X4" /></a></p></td> // There's a field in my DB called categories, and 'docks' is the value assigned to the products
      <td align="center"><p>Floating Docks</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/floating dock/100225279.jpg" width="100" height="60" alt="Floating Dock" /></p></td>
      <td align="center"><p>Frame Docks</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/frame dock/frameDock.jpg" width="100" height="64" alt="Frame Dock" /></p></td>
      <td align="center"><p>Pipe Docks</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/pipe dock/PN99002_16X4_SECTION_LG.jpg" width="100" height="64" alt="Pipe Dock" /></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><p>Boat Lifts</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/boat lifts/GM1060_LG.jpg" width="100" height="64" alt="Boat Lift" /></p></td>
      <td align="center"><p>Boat Lift Accessories</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/boat lift acceessories/canopy_lg (1).png" width="100" height="64" alt="Boat Lift Accessory" /></p></td>
      <td align="center"><p>Rollers &amp; Caddies</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/rollers and caddies/caddy270 (1).jpg" width="100" height="64" alt="Caddy" /></p></td>
      <td align="center"><p>Accessories</p>
        <p><img src="inventory_images/accessorries/2step_LG.png" width="100" height="64" alt="Accessory" /></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in category.php I'm trying to create a variable called $dynamicList with all the products that have "dock" as a category. But when I echo out $dynamicList nothing is rendered.

```
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$category=$_GET['category'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$category' LIMIT 6");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="100" height="64" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<meta name="Description" content="Lightweight aluminum boat docks, lifts, and accessories" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Aluminum boat dock ladder lift water wheels" />
<script src="scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<title><?php echo $category; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</style>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
<?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p><?php echo $dynamicList;?><br />
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>          <h2>&nbsp;</h2></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw you should escape spaces in your src strings with %20

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code? The if/then statement in its current form seems to cover all possibilites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: $dynamicList is nested in a condition statement. Just write

```
$dynamicList = '';
```

before your query

What is the current output on the page? Are the # of rows returned in the query = 0?
You should also sanitize your $category input using mysql_real_escape_string()

```
WHERE category ='".mysql_real_escape_string($category)."' ...
```

Comment: "Are the # of rows = 0" if it were so, the output must has been "We have no products listed in our store yet.", but the questions states, that the output is empty — which can't be true either with the code above?! Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** sanitize first the strings using this function:

```
public static function real_escape($string)
{
    if (null != $string) {
        $string = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $string : addslashes($string);
        return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Or better use third party script like [phpDataMapper](http://www.phpdatamapper.com/)

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$category' LIMIT 6");
```

should be

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='".$category."' LIMIT 6");
```

This is the only error I can discover for now

Comment: Doesn't fix it, should also be sanitized.

Comment: `$category` contains a string, and must be bounded by single-quotes within the query. If you are worried about variable interpolation, the entire query string is bounded by double-quotes, so `$category` will be interpreted properly.

Comment: bouding it in single-quotes is very unsecure, when I tried that out, it wouldn't work everytime

Comment: @MrRap, can you show us an example of an SQL statement that will insert a string value into a string-type field (char, varchar, text) that _does not_ require quotes around the value?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I got it working. The comments were very helpful in learning how to write good code!